# C# Excel how to add hyperlink with cell link

Tags: c#, excel, hyperlink

I`ll try to work with Excel using C#.

I need to add a hyperlink, which using the value of another cell. If this value in document is changed, hyperlink also must change.

This code:

```
curSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(curSheet.get_Range("c1"), "https://www.google.ru/?q=" + curSheet.get_Range("b1").Value)
```

will give me a fixed link. How can I create a dynamic link, which contain a sublink to cell, not cell value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `HYPERLINK` formula?

```
curSheet.get_Range("c1").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.ru/?q="" & b1)"
```

Comment: I tried to do such a way, however, I get a link like this:

www.google.ru/q=!b1.

Answer (score 3):

use this code:

```
Excel.Worksheet sh;
sh.Hyperlinks.Add(sh.Cells[1, 1], "http://www.Sharifsoft.com/", Type.Missing, "Sharifsoft", "www.Sharifsoft.com");
```

I found this answer in [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61bfcc2a-b355-435c-a8e8-46db4aceb423/create-a-hyperlink-in-excel-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 2):

you can try do below this:

```
 var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 var excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
 var excelWS = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelWB.Worksheets[1];
 var excelCell = excelWS.get_Range("A1", "A1");
 excelWS.Hyperlinks.Add(excelCell, "https://stackoverflow.com/", Type.Missing, "Stackoverflow", "Stackoverflow");
```