# VB.NET System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '0x800A03EC'

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm trying to change the cell's value on excel but I get this error (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '0x800A03EC') when I run this part of the code

```
Private Sub SaveHeaderBut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveHeaderBut.Click
    objSheet = objBook.Sheets("Header")
    objSheet.Cells("5", "9").value = ExCountry_txt.Text
    objSheet.Cells("5", "10").value = ExCoName_txt.Text
    objSheet.Cells("5", "11").value = ExCoAddress_txt.Text
```

This part of the code is in a different form and the function that opens the excel application is in a module

```
Module Module1
Public objApp As Excel.Application
Public objBook As Excel._Workbook
Public objBooks As Excel.Workbooks
Public objSheets As Excel.Sheets
Public objSheet As Excel._Worksheet
Public range As Excel.Range

Public Sub Criarligação()
    objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    objApp.Visible = False
    'Clean up a little.
    range = Nothing
    objSheet = Nothing
    objSheets = Nothing
    objBooks = Nothing
End Sub
```

To get to form2 I'm using this sub

```
    Private Sub NewFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewFileToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim template = "C:\Tabelasdexpedição\Template"
    Criarligação()
    objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Open(template)

    Dim fr2 As New Form2
    fr2.Show()
```

I'm asking for help because I cant understand the error message nor what's creating it.

Comment: Start by enabling [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72872634/10024425 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794540/10024425 , and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759270/10024425 ,

Comment: The error is probably caused because you used `objSheet.Cells("5", "9").value` instead of `objSheet.Cells(5, 9).value`.

Comment: the problem was with the "" in the cells ;w; thank you