Find the address of the hyperlink in a cell in excel with the VB code?
I am using following code to find the address but am unable to find the cell reference
For i = 5 To lastRow ' Assuming row 1 is header
    ' Get the cell containing the hyperlink in column S
    Set linkCell = wsSource.Cells(i, "S")
    
    ' Check if the cell has a hyperlink
    If linkCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        ' Get the hyperlink object
        Set hyperlink = linkCell.Hyperlinks(1) ' Assuming only one hyperlink in the cell
        
        ' Get the address of the hyperlink
        linkAddress = hyperlink.Address
        'linkAddress = linkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
        
        ' Extract the cell reference from the hyperlink address
        cellReference = Right(linkAddress, Len(linkAddress) - InStrRev(linkAddress, "#"))
        'wsSource.Cells(i, "T").Value = cellReference
        ' Print the cell reference
        'Debug.Print "Cell Reference in Hyperlink: " & cellReference
        
        ' Now you can use the cell reference to perform further actions in the destination sheet
        ' For example, you can get the value from the destination sheet using the cell reference
        ' newValue = wsDestination.Range(cellReference).Value
    End If
Next i

Note that the linkCell.Hyprelinks.Count is 1 and the code goes through the "if condition" but does not find the cellReference I was expecting to get the cell reference to location where the hyperlink is pointing to. For some reason it is not returning the address.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72872634/10024425 (see code under CreateExcelWorkbook). It shows two ways hyperlinks can be created. Understanding this, should be helpful.

When referring to a range within the workbook you have to use SubAddress instead of Address
